# pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xd0': Data.Text.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream

Tags: encoding, utf-8, pdf-generation, pandoc

I'm getting this error when I made `pandoc --filter pandoc-citeproc myfile.markdown myfile.pdf`

> pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xd0': Data.Text.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream

I have searched [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/XTyj3KogsVs) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97843/how-to-interpret-message-invalid-utf-8-stream-when-trying-to-convert-a-tex-fil), but I have double checked from the text editor and my file is UTF-8 encoded. It has accented Spanish characters, but the same command worked without anyproblem in the past. Any pointers to a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I solve the issue adding `| iconv -t utf-8 |` to the pipeline

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My bad. The problem is related with the command I use to tell pandoc to create the pdf ouput. The proper command should be:

```
pandoc --filter pandoc-citeproc myfile.markdown -o myfile.pdf
```

note the `-o` flag between the input markdown file and the ouput pdf file. That's why I got the same utf-8 message that the people trying to convert from pdf to other formats documented in my links.

Answer (score 3):

## Check JabRef encoding

In my case, I bumped into a similar error when converting [Pandoc Markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) to XHTML. The culprit was a set of [BibTeX citations](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations) which [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) had encoded by default in `ISO8859_1`.

This default JabRef behaviour can be changed once and for all by setting `Default encoding:` to `UTF8` in JabRef's `Options > Preferences > General` menu.